# Check if parameter contains vowels in string

Tags: java, if-statement, parameters, contains

I am kind of new to Java. I am trying to check if a given parameter contains vowels and if so, return a words. This is what I have so far:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String nome = "Leonardo";
        int lunghezza = nome.length();
        char[] vocali = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};  
        System.out.println("Lunghezza parola: " + lunghezza);
            
        if (lunghezza > 5) {
            System.out.println("E' una parola piu' lunga di 5 lettere");
        } else if (lunghezza < 5) {
            System.out.println("E' una parola piu' corta di 5 lettere");
        }
        
        if (nome.contains('a','e','i','o','u')) {
            System.out.println("Contiene vocali");
        }

        //System.out.println(nome.contains(vocali));
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to ask a question or tell us what problem you are facing. Currently your post really doesn't tell us what your actual problem is.

Comment: and *if* you are getting an error, also write that together with the error message and location...

Comment: You can use a regex: `if (nome.matches(".*[aeiou].*")) {`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I haven't researched this feature yet but it's what I was looking for @g00se

Answer (score 1):

When I ask you: "Hey, does this word contain an a, e, i, o, or u" you know what I mean. But my question isn't actually clear, you just apply a lifetime of human knowledge to the situation and some empathy (you walk in my shoes and figure out what kinds of questions one might ask and use that as part of the process of understanding what I mean).

Computers just aren't like that. They need to be told precisely what to do and will do precisely what you say no matter how stupid it is. [Here is a youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ct-lOOUqmyY) of a dad asking his kids to write down the recipe for peanutbutter and jelly sandwiches and he follows it exactly (with disastrously hilarious results, of course). **Programming is exactly like that**.

Hence, this: `if (nome.contains('a','e','i','o','u')) {` doesn't work - it doesn't even make sense. Are you asking if it contains at least 1 of those letters? All of them?

The usual solution is - well, it's a programming language - program it. Instead of looking for a single 'method' that does exactly what you want, treat methods as very simple verbs. There is no verb that means 'cook the rice for 8 minutes'. There's a verb that means 'cook'. There are additional words you can use to indicate '.. for 8 minutes'. No verb will ever exist that precisely means 'cook it for 8 minutes'. Same here. There is no one method. Write code that does what you want:

```
boolean found = false;
for (String vocale : vocali) {
  if (nome.contains(vocale)) {
    found = true;
    break;
  }
}

if (found) {
  System.out.println("Contiene vocali");
}
```

Additional complication is that the 'verb' ".contains(someChar)" doesn't exist, only ".contains(someString)" exists, so change your `vocali` array to be of type `String[]` and to use double quotes to fix that. Or use `.indexOf(someChar) > -1` instead (indexOf *does* have an overload that works on chars).

With the stream API this works too:

```
boolean found = nome.chars()
  .anyMatch(c -> Arrays.binarySearch(vocali, c) > -1);
```

This requires that you write your `vocali` in alphabetical order (binary search **requires** that the array you are searching through is sorted). I'm assuming you haven't covered lambdas (also known as closures) in your course yet so you might want to forget about this `anyMatch` stuff until later.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation,
the only thing i don't understand is:
|
for (String vocale : vocali) {
|
I have no vocale but only vocali

Comment: The moment you do `String vocale` you now have `vocale` in that scope (that is, only inside the subsequent `for` block.

Comment: @EmanueleSiragusa You might want to follow some basic tutorials first. `for (String x : someListyThing)` runs the loop once for every element in 'someListyThing', declares a variable named `x`, which exists inside that loop, and holds the value of someListyThing we are on. This is all basic java 101 and not appropriate for SO.

Comment: Could you adapt it to my code? @zwitserloot

Comment: @EmanueleSiragusa You should read what Stack Overflow is for. It's not 'please do my homework for me' nor is it 'please explain first-steps java for me'.

Comment: Indeed that's what I meant, seeing it integrated into a simple code I created for practice would help me understand, there is no homework or work to do here @rzwitserloot

Answer (score 0):

```
String nome = "Leonardo";
        int lunghezza = nome.length();
        char[] vocali = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
        System.out.println("Lunghezza parola: " + lunghezza);

        if (lunghezza > 5) {
            System.out.println("E' una parola piu' lunga di 5 lettere");
        } else if (lunghezza < 5) {
            System.out.println("E' una parola piu' corta di 5 lettere");
        }
        //check whether a single character contains in nome
        if (nome.contains("e")) {
            System.out.println("Contiene vocali");
        }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, but how can I avoid doing many - if (name.contains("e")) - and search directly inside an array?

Comment: You can use the following code snippets for that. `for(int i=0; i<nome.length(); i++) {
            if(nome.charAt(i) == 'a'|| nome.charAt(i) == 'e'|| 
            nome.charAt(i) == 'i' || nome.charAt(i) == 'o' || 
            nome.charAt(i) == 'u')
            System.out.println("Contiene vocali");
    } `

Comment: Please don't add comments to clarify; code is unreadable in comments. [Edit] your answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid looping through the string one character at a time. It is error-prone and not an optimal way to do this.

Instead, you can use "regular expressions", which is a string matching framework with its own syntax. It is used in many different languages, including Java.

To get a quick introduction, you could check out this: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_regex.asp

It is a very strong and widely used technology for string matching, and have many different features, depending on your needs.

For your particular example, the matching could be done like this:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String nomo = "Leonardo";

        // Create a regex pattern which matches any of the listed vowels:
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[aeiou]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        // Create a matcher which checks the pattern with the provided name:
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(nomo);

        // Check if we have a match:
        boolean matchFound = matcher.find();
        if (matchFound) {
            System.out.println('Contiene vocali');
        }
    }
}
```

There are many online testers where you can try out your regular expressions. For example, you could check out this: https://regex101.com/

Happy coding. :-)